# Convert Text from EditText to Integer Value Error

Tags: java, android, android-edittext, setvalue

So I'm developing currently my own private App which I want to use only for me and maybe some friends.
Well I'm german so my english is maybe not the best I hope you can forgive me.

Now my Problem is that I want to set in my Optionsmenu a Budget for the current month to keep track of. I'm doing that by using an EditText with a Button.

Now I want to save this String which is getting entered in my EditText to a String value and a Integer value because I want to show the Value in a TextView on my MainPage and use the Integer value to calculate my current budget I got and so on.

Now I'm showing you guys my code and I hope u can tell me whats wrong with it.
I'm trying to get my Value in the Options class which is related to my OptionsMenu and later Trying to get the Value out of my Options class into my Main class.

```
public class Options extends Activity {
Button GoBack, SetBudget;
private int Budget;
String BudgetString = "";
EditText BudgetEdit;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.options);
    GoBack = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
    GoBack.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Intent GoBackToMain = new Intent("com.lunarrepublic.STARTINGPOINT");
            startActivity(GoBackToMain);

        }
    });

    SetBudget = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button8);

    SetBudget.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            BudgetEdit = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
            BudgetString = EditText.getText();
            //In the Line above this is  the error "Type mismatch. Cannot convert Editable to String
            Budget = Integer.parseInt(BudgetString);

        }
    });
}
```

But if I try to set my "BudgetString" to Editable It won't work either.
The GoBack Button is unnecessary for my problem here so you don't have to read over it.

So I hope you guys understood what my problem is and can maybe help me getting it fixed

Thanks in advance

Comment: `BudgetString = EditText.getText().toString();`

Comment: `Editable` is not a `String` actually. You have to use `toString()` to convert to the data type the `parseInt()` can accept.

Comment: `BudgetString = EditText.getText();`, it's wrong, Use your object `BudgetEdit` instead. Also keep `Budget = Integer.parseInt(BudgetString);` within try catch to catch any number format exception.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is wrong

```
BudgetString = EditText.getText();
```

Use below one

```
BudgetString = BudgetEdit.getText().toString();
```

Comment: My Error is gone so I think this is the answer :)

Thank you very much but before i can verify it I have to fix my app first. Seems like I did something wrong last night because after my loading screen disappears my app crashes.

Comment: @NhatNienne Happy developement

Comment: Thank you very much Man
You saved my day :D I fixed my error idk why but my app crashed because I had an unused Variable and an unused EditText Parameter in my Main Class lol

Answer (score 0):

change this

```
    SetBudget.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        BudgetEdit = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
        BudgetString = EditText.getText();
        //In the Line above this is  the error "Type mismatch. Cannot convert Editable to String
        Budget = Integer.parseInt(BudgetString);

    }
});
```

to

```
   SetBudget.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        BudgetEdit = (EditText) Options.this.findViewById(R.id.editText1);
        BudgetString = BudgetEdit.getText();
        //In the Line above this is  the error "Type mismatch. Cannot convert Editable to String
        Budget = Integer.parseInt(BudgetString);

    }
});
```